# How to send data from Flutter to PHP then to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, flutter

I am able to get data from MySQL to php and from PHP to my flutter app, I am also able to send data from php to MySQL database, but I am facing issues in sending data from flutter to php file

I have refered this video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4Q6lEhmwCY".
Since it didn't work I have cloned this repository to check its working

I am using the below syntax in .php file to receive value which throws error: undefined index

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
```

Also when in checked for error this was given as solution which just returns $action value as true every time

```
$action =  !isset($_POST['action']);
```

Basically I just want to know to send any string or int value from Flutter to .php file

Comment: please post your http post code so we can help

Comment: The code shown seems to conclusively demonstrate that a value named "action" is not being included in the POST data values.  Can you indicate/demonstrate specifically why you expect otherwise?